# Creating a variable in a Cypress test to store text on a page in order to compare it against text on a different page

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to create a variable in my cypress test that will allow me to store info from one web page for when I click a link and leave the page. I want to compare a word from this first page to a word on the second.

```
describe("Logged-in Item Page", () => {

 before(() => {
   cy.*login command*().then((*login stuff*) => {
     cy.website_login(*login info*);
   });
 });
 beforeEach(() => {
   cy.visit(Cypress.env("baseUrl") + "*URL*")
 });
 
 it("Verify My Store opens", () => {
       return new Cypress.Promise(resolve => {
         cy.get("*selector*").then($value => {
           const storeName = $value.text().split(' ')[0];
           resolve(storeName);
         });
         cy.log(storeName)
       });
   });
});
```

It is worth to mention that I tried putting var Storename; outside of this area and removing the var keyword inside to cy.get() part but still no luck. As well I tried doing const storeName instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of its asynchronous nature, when you call `storeName`  outside the `.then($value => {` it happens that the callback hasn't been done yet, so the value is not assigned.

Instead, you can use Cypress promises, so Cypress will wait until the promises is resolved.

```
    it("Verify My Store opens", async () => {
        const storeName = await new Cypress.Promise((resolve) => {
            cy.get("selector").then($value => {
                resolve($value.text().split(' ')[0])
            })
        })
        cy.log(storeName)

   })
```